# Whats the best way to create a debugging history log for an Android application

Tags: android, debugging, logging

So I have an android application that has a myriad of activities (intents?) which all do their own thing. We were wanting to create a sort of debug log though, one where you can see what the user has been through and error that occurs. You may have had to send one before if you've run into a bug with a program you've used.

My initial thoughts are to just create a class where I can send information/data to and it just writes it onto a text file. It would need to be accessible across all the activities so that I can easily write to it and re-use it.

I do wonder whether that's a good way to go through, noted that it doesn't really save any actual errors but only data I tell it to. And I'm not sure if its a great idea to be constantly opening->writing->closing a file for a debug log.

Is there a smarter way? Or a common pattern that would be good to use?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Sentry's Android SDK, will automatically report errors and exceptions in your application.
The Sentry SDK catches the exception right before the crash and builds a crash report that will persist to the disk. The SDK will try to send the report right after the crash, but since the environment may be unstable at the crash time, the report is guaranteed to send once the application is started again.

You can see full documentation [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/)